# In Objective C, is there a difference between if (object == nil) and if (nil == object)?

Tags: objective-c, coding-style, assignment-operator, comparison-operators

I would lean towards

```
if (object == nil)
```

but I've noticed in some tutorials the use of

```
if (nil == object)
```

Is this just a style thing, or is there some justified rationale for using either format?

Comment: Its just style but at @Jim says the 2nd option is safer in the event of a typo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is typically done to prevent using an assignment operator instead of a comparison operator. If you accidently typed this for instance:

```
if (object = nil)
```

It may compile but it isn't what you intended.

By using the second form you will ensure a compile time error if you mistype it, as nil cant be used as the left operand in assignments.

Please note I'm not an objective C programmer, but this question is generic to a lot of languages.

Comment: OK. It seems to me though that if you have enough presence of mind to put the nil first (in case you type a single =), you've already reminded yourself to do the double ==. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, I usually don't bother with the second form, but some people prefer it just to be safe, and prevent sometimes hard to find bugs.

Answer (score 2):

The `if (nil == object)` version protects you better in case you accidentally put = instead of ==.